# Semi-transparent colors in Google Charts?

Tags: charts, colors, google-visualization, alpha-transparency, color-palette

A call like

```
chart.draw(data, { colors: ['#e0440e', '#e6693e', '#ec8f6e', ...], ... });
```

[creates a chart with colors looking like semi-transparent](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_charts). However, we passed RGB colors, with no alpha parameter!

In other chart apps (like jqPlot, CanvasJS etc) you may pass ***rgba*** calls instead, like in

```
[ 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)', 'rgba(0,255,0,0.5)', ...]
```

Google Charts does not seem to support this. But is there any other way to pass RGBA custom colors instead, with a simple syntax?

PS: there is a somehow similar question for pie charts, but mine is different, for custom color palettes.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing, I believe the only way possible is to write JavaScript that manipulates SVG.

Comment: For [bar chars](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart), you can provide `dataOpacity` property that is documented to set opacity for all series. What is not documented is that it can be provided on per-series basis, inside the `series: ` element, and then it will control transparency all data points in a single series. As for individual data points in a series, there is [`fill-opacity` property](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart?#column-styles) that can be provided from a `{role: "style"}` data column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

once the `'ready'` event fires on the chart, you can modify the svg

just need a way to find the chart elements you want to modify

in the following working snippet, random colors are used to feed the chart

then when `'ready'` fires, those colors are found and replaced with rgba

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Y1', 'Y2'],
    ['2010', 10, 14],
    ['2020', 14, 22],
    ['2030', 16, 24],
    ['2040', 22, 30],
    ['2050', 28, 36]
  ]);

  var seriesColors = ['#00ffff', '#ff00ff'];
  var rgbaMap = {
    '#00ffff': 'rgba(0,255,0,0.5)',
    '#ff00ff': 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)'
  };

  var options = {
    colors: seriesColors,
  };

  var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(chartDiv);

  // modify svg
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(chartDiv.getElementsByTagName('rect'), function(rect) {
      if (seriesColors.indexOf(rect.getAttribute('fill')) > -1) {
        rect.setAttribute('fill', rgbaMap[rect.getAttribute('fill')]);
      }
    });
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: great solution! To make it more generic (to work with a pie as well), I processed all elems with a fill attribute within the svg tag: jQuery syntax: $("svg").find("*[fill]").each(...).

Comment: that works too -- just fyi: use HEX values to feed chart instead of color _names_, such as `'red', 'black'` -- the chart will change `fill` value to HEX equivalent anyway (`'#ff0000', '#000000'`) -- which could cause lookup to fail...

Comment: we should always use web color values in hex, or rgba when extended with opacity. I think it's bad practice and hard to maintain to mix it up with color names or 3-digit notation (as in #fa0 for #ffaa00). Some other important remark: all hex values should be in lower case, otherwise the code won't work! This is because all fill values such as #FFAA00 are automatically translated into #ffaa00.

Answer (score 0):

Use $.attr('opacity', value) for all elements filtered by colors. exapmle with jQuery...

```js
var options = {
  colors: ['#ff5722', '#1976D2', '#2196f3', '#BBDEFB', '#BDBDBD']
  },
  conteiner = $('div'),
  data = {},//some data
  chart = new
google.visualization.PieChart(conteiner);

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    chartSetColorOpacity(conteiner, 0.8, options.colors);
});

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseout', function () {
    chartSetColorOpacity(conteiner, 0.8, options.colors);
});

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', function (target) {
    chartSetColorOpacity(conteiner, 0.8, options.colors);
});

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function (target) {
    chartSetColorOpacity(conteiner, 0.8, options.colors);
});

chart.draw(data, options);
        
function chartSetColorOpacity($container, opacity, matchColors){

    $container = $($container);

    if(!$container.is('svg')){
        $container = $container.find('svg');
    }

    if(typeof opacity === "number"){
        opacity = String(opacity);
    }else if(typeof opacity !== "string"){
        throw new Error('function chartSetColorOpacity(): opacity is not correct! opacity=' + opacity);
    }

    if(matchColors){
        if(typeof matchColors === "string") {
            matchColors = [matchColors];
        }
    }else {
        matchColors = false;
    }

    $container.find('*[fill]:not(opacity)').each(function(indx, element){

        var $this = $(this);

        if(matchColors !== false) {

            var matched = false,
                color = $this.attr('fill').toUpperCase();

            for (var i = matchColors.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (matchColors[i].toUpperCase() == color) {
                    matched = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!matched) return;

        }

        $this.attr('opacity', opacity);

    });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```