# Dynamic google charts configuration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization, pygooglechart

We're planning to use google charts in our project and we use Angular JS for front end. (New to both Angular & Google charts)

Does **Google chart** provide any **readymade UI** for configuring each type of chart ?

If user select a chart type, it should show the user the configurations and once user selects , it is applied for that chart.

Ex:

1. If Pie chart is selected "pieHole" field will be displayed.
2. If bar chart is selected "isStacked" field will be displayed.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out the [`ChartEditor` Class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_charteditor)

The following working snippet opens a chart editor dialog with a populated pie chart

When the chart editor opens, see the **Customize** tab for the various chart options

Click "OK" to save the chart to a `<div>` on the page

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var chartEditor = null;

    // Create the chart to edit
    var chartWrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'PieChart',
      dataTable: new google.visualization.DataTable({
        "cols": [
          {"label": "Country", "type": "string"},
          {"label": "# of Devices", "type": "number"}
        ],
        "rows": [
          {"c": [{"v": "Canada"}, {"v": 33}]},
          {"c": [{"v": "Mexico"}, {"v": 33}]},
          {"c": [{"v": "USA"}, {"v": 34}]}
        ]
      })
    });
    chartEditor = new google.visualization.ChartEditor();
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chartEditor, 'ok', redrawChart);
    chartEditor.openDialog(chartWrapper, {});

    // On "OK" save the chart to a <div> on the page.
    function redrawChart(){
      chartEditor.getChartWrapper().draw(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    }
  },
  packages:['charteditor', 'controls']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome :) thanks a lot.. will look into that class :)

Comment: one more question. do we need to select only from those 80 colors in that color palette ?? what we need to do if the user have to use RGB numbers or Hex numbers for choosing colors ??

Comment: you can feed your own colors to the `colors` option of the chart, or use one of the other ways to provide colors, such as a `'style'` column -- as for RGB, these are currently not supported -- however, chart colors can be changed manually after the chart has drawn -- [here is a working example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40284460/5090771) using `rgba(...)`

Comment: i want to save the chart configurations once and get the data at different times and then draw the chart using the saved config with data. For that i want to use chartEditor class. So, if the user wants to select the colors it should be flexible to select any colors in chartEditor.  I want to know how to add more colors to chartEditor color palette.  pl help