# Google Time-Date Chart Color display in android webview

Tags: android, google-visualization, android-webview, pygooglechart

Here i'm trying to set column color to "#FFFFFF00". 
This color code **working proper in Desktop or laptop browser**.
But, while using same method trying to load chart in A**ndroid device using webview** display message like **'#FFFFFF00' is not valid hex color**

**Here is Android Device Screen**
[image]

**Here is Web browser screen**
[image: **enter image description here**]

Here is the code what i'm using.

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var jsonObj = {"graphData":[{"label":"Data1","startTime":1533875458929,"endTime":1533882249978},{"label":"Data1","startTime":1533883034531,"endTime":1533884571783},{"label":"Data3","startTime":1533885078579,"endTime":1533885080601},{"label":"Data2","startTime":1533885080692,"endTime":1533885085560},{"label":"Data2","startTime":1533885288787,"endTime":1533885289822},{"label":"Data1","startTime":1533885291855,"endTime":1533885294676},{"label":"Data1","startTime":1533885299333,"endTime":1533886561000},{"label":"Data1","startTime":1533895149007,"endTime":1533906604650},{"label":"Data2","startTime":1533895309727,"endTime":1533895312451},{"label":"Data3","startTime":1533895309784,"endTime":1533895312367},{"label":"Data2","startTime":1533895797279,"endTime":1533895804452},{"label":"Data3","startTime":1533895797503,"endTime":1533895804848},{"label":"Data2","startTime":1533895807047,"endTime":1533895812201},{"label":"Data3","startTime":1533895807276,"endTime":1533895812003},{"label":"Data3","startTime":1533897706544,"endTime":1533897709518},{"label":"Data2","startTime":1533897706714,"endTime":1533897709651},{"label":"Data3","startTime":1533897711492,"endTime":1533897712438},{"label":"Data2","startTime":1533897711685,"endTime":1533897712545},{"label":"Data2","startTime":1533897732040,"endTime":1533897787031},{"label":"Data3","startTime":1533897732126,"endTime":1533897772174},{"label":"Data2","startTime":1533897788230,"endTime":1533897790235},{"label":"Data2","startTime":1533897848566,"endTime":1533897852356},{"label":"Data3","startTime":1533897848661,"endTime":1533897852427},{"label":"Data3","startTime":1533897977422,"endTime":1533897979531},{"label":"Data2","startTime":1533897977571,"endTime":1533897979731},{"label":"Data3","startTime":1533898561521,"endTime":1533898563708},{"label":"Data2","startTime":1533898561641,"endTime":1533898563783},{"label":"Data3","startTime":1533898565041,"endTime":1533898567063},{"label":"Data2","startTime":1533898565254,"endTime":1533898567174},{"label":"Data3","startTime":1533899674499,"endTime":1533899678492},{"label":"Data2","startTime":1533899674587,"endTime":1533899677559},{"label":"Data3","startTime":1533899786994,"endTime":1533899989725},{"label":"Data2","startTime":1533899787081,"endTime":1533899989806},{"label":"Light","startTime":1533899787081,"endTime":1533899989806}],"colorsData":{"Data3":"green","Data2":"green","Data1":"red","Light":"#FFFFFF00"}};

        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Equipment'});
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start'});
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End'});



        var chartData = jsonObj.graphData;
       var rowData = new Array(chartData.length);
       var number = 0;
      for (i in chartData) {
        rowData[i] = [chartData[i].label,new Date(chartData[i].startTime),new Date(chartData[i].endTime)];
      }

        dataTable.addRows(rowData);





    var colors = [];
    var columns = [];
    var colorMap = jsonObj.colorsData;


    for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {

        columns.push(dataTable.getValue(i, 0));

    }

    let unique = columns.filter((it, i, ar) => ar.indexOf(it) === i);
  
    for (var i = 0; i < unique.length; i++) {


        colors.push(colorMap[unique[i]]);

    }
   




      var options = {
        height: 10,
        timeline: {
          groupByRowLabel: true,
          colorByRowLabel: true
        },
         is3D:true,
          colors: colors
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(dataTable, options);
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: google charts does not support RGBA, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40284460/5090771)...

Comment: @WhiteHat how can i show empty row in Time Date chart?

Comment: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49369016/5090771) for adding blank rows...